# How to show image in Bluetooth device list instead of Bluetooth device name.?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

In my app I want to show photo and name instead of Bluetooth name without connecting Bluetooth..
like shown in image.
[image]
There is list of searched Bluetooth device using search button in my app,
By default in list, there is show name of Bluetooth , but I want to show image and name which is in another device's database.
How can I do that.? Please give me any example or some way.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it impossible to advertise so big piece of information as image.

So I see at least 2 possible solutions:

- When you see that device first time - show stub-image, but on first connection, first of all pass image and store it somewhere. So on next search you will be able to show other device's image
- Use server side, where your app will upload device's image and during bluetooth devices search, it will ask server side if other device's image is already exist and use it

Comment: Is there possible with paired device? I just want to send 3 string only , 1 string of Image base64, 2nd is name and 3rd is name of color.  Is it possible?

Comment: You are asking if it possible to send data via bluetooth? Yes it possible.